# Using TextArea in C# and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#

I am using textArea to take user input this textArea'id is calling c# and javaScript function when I add run at the server the javaScript function won't work when I remove it c# function won't work what the solution is?

Comment: what do you mean about c#, which framework ? asp.net mvc ? razor ? webform ?

Comment: Add code samples

Comment: fixed some grammar issues

Answer (score 0):

Please add ClientIDMode="Static" as an attribute after runat

```
<asp:TextBox id="TextArea1" TextMode="multiline" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
      <button id="btnid" type="button">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<script>
  $('#btnid').click(function () {
    var myvalue = $("#comment").val();
    alert(myvalue);
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```